# Write nicely formatted list with write function

Tags: python

I have two lists with numbers and I want them to be written out nicely, just like what I get from `print item1, item2`. Can anybody help?

```
outfile = open("tabal_t_y.dat", "w")
for item1, item2 in zip(t, y):
    outfile.write()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: you should use `with` to open your files

Answer (score 2):

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement)

> evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting object… If an object is not a string, it is first converted to a string using the rules for string conversions… A space is written before each object is (converted and) written…

However, if you read a bit farther in the docs:

> `print` also has an extended form… sometimes referred to as “print chevron.” In this form, the first expression after the `>>` must evaluate to a “file-like” object… the subsequent expressions are printed to this file object…

So, you don't *have* to do this with `outfile.write` at all, you can just do this:

```
print >>outfile, item1, item2
```

---

But if you want to use `outfile.write`, you can do everything `print` does by yourself, in two different ways:

First, you can convert the outputs to strings, then join them with spaces:

```
outfile.write(' '.join(map(str, (item1, item2))))

outfile.write(str(item1) + ' ' + str(item2))

def write_things(f, *things):
    f.write(' '.join(map(str, things))))
write_things(outfile, item1, item2)
```

… or anything else you feel comfortable with.

Or you can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
outfile.write('{} {}'.format(item1, item2))
```